# Java vitual machine for Macintosh El Capitan

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to install the latest Java Virtual Machine on my Mac to use Eclipse for SW development. I have installed Java from the Oracle website, and using the Java control panel on my Mac it shows "Java 8 Update 91" which seems to be the latest version. When starting Eclipse for installation (dmg file) a window pops up and tells me that I have the JVM 1.6.0 installed and I should install at least version 1.7.0.
The Java control panel, which can be used for updates, shows me that I have the latest version of Java installed though, so I don't know what is the matter. Any hints or tips?

Comment: You probably have several different versions of Java installed and JAVA_HOME is referring to the old version. What you get if you type in terminal (or other console you use) this: java -version ? And what you get if you type this: echo $JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: Hi! When I type in java -version, I get the answer that the Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment is the build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833. Also, I get Java Hotspot (TM) 64-bit server VM(build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode). Further, typing in "echo $JAVA_HOME" does not return anything, just an empty line, then the command line prompt.

Comment: So you do have java 6 installed and it is referred by default. Could you pls also make this command: ls -la /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/ and copy the output here

Comment: command typed in:
ls -la /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
result :

May 13 22:16 ..
May 13 22:16 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
May 13 22:16 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
May 13 22:16 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
May 13 22:16 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
May 13 22:16 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
May 13 22:16 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
May 13 22:16 A
May 13 22:16 Current -> A
May 13 22:16 CurrentJDK -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents

Comment: Hmm, and if you open the folder /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines - do you have a folder jdk1.8.0_91.jdk or something similar there?

Comment: Yes, there is the folder 1.6.0.jdk

Comment: Strange that you do not have a folder for 1.8.0 jdk... Do you know the folder where you have 1.8.0 installed? And did you download your 1.8. java (exectly the JDK part) from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html ?

Comment: Just to be clear - for SW development you need **JDK** - you have installed it, right?

Comment: Yes, I did download and install the SDK part from the link you posted (oracle site). Also, there is only the folder 1.6.0.jdk in the mentioned path

Comment: We need to find out where your jdk 1.8.0 is located. I have Update 92 and the folder is named "jdk1.8.0_92.jdk" so let's try this for 91 update (hope this would work) - `sudo find / -name jdk1.8.0_91.jdk` When we find where this jdk is located, we will make java_home pointing on this folder

Comment: I typed in the command: sudo find / -name jdk1.8.0_91.jdk and for the following result: /dev/fd/3 not a directory   And also: /dev/fd/4 : Not a directory

Comment: `find` is very slow command, did you wait till the end? And another option - maybe you have your java 8 here - /System/Library/Java/JavaFrameworks/ ?